# Page Breaking/ Pagination in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I need to show only fixed number of rows per page in our ssrs report. I surfed the solutions in internet, all of them requires to add a new group in report on the top on parent group. Is it possible to add pagination without creating a new group / In a existing group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using grouping or expressions the easiest way is to change the page size in the report properties(Page Setup).

Change the `Paper Size` to `Custom` and change the `Height` to desired `show the desired number of rows`.

[image]